# Passing c-style string to sources in CMakeList.txt

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to have a definition with a string value: "v1.1.1"
However, when I tried the following command:

```
add_definitions(-DVERSION="v1.1.1")
//or set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -DVERSION=\"v1.1.1\")
//as well as set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -DVERSION="\"v1.1.1\"")
```

and used v1.1.1 in my source file, in a command like printf("%s\n", v1.1.1) 
I got v1.1.1 in my c/c++ sources code without the quotes, which is not a valid string literal.
how do I define this correctly in a CMakeList.txt file?

Comment: "... and used v1.1.1 in my source file ..." - Do you mean "and used VERSION in my source file"? Otherwise the code doesn't use macro-definition at all.

Comment: thank you!  I solved the problem by doing this: #define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define STR(s) #s